# jQuery is not defined webpack 4.x.x

Tags: jquery, npm, webpack

I've been wracking my brain all day about this, and I've been trying pretty hard to resolve this on my own.

I have two files, a webpack.config.js which contains all of my src code with helping loaders; and a web.config.vendor.js which should contain all my vendor libraries. I prefer it this way since I don't want to keep running webpack against vendor files AND my own src code. I have seen this type of configuration many times, and each time seems like a copy of the other.

Notes:

- The output of webpack.config.js is called main.js
- The output of webpack.config.js is called vendor.js
- Vendor.js loads up before main.js

In webpack.config.vendor.js I have the following:

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    moment: 'moment',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    /* For modal, you will need to add tether */
  })
```

Here are the scripts I was using:

- webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress
- webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js --progress

When I run this, none of the packages which calls on jQuery works, it gives me "jQuery is not defined". However, when I take the same code above and place it in webpack.config.js, then it works as expected.

Now I'm wondering, is the reason why I'm getting a "jQuery not defined" is because it's defined in vendor.js where there is no way to provide global exposure to the node packages? And that the reason why jQuery IS defined is that the components are in the same file (main.js)??

I also tried expose-loader in my webconfig.config.vendor.js and that didn't work either.